# Query about companies and regions

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm doing some exercises about SQL right now.

I have a database with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE regions(
region_id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
region_name        TEXT NOT NULL,
number_of_customers INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE region_borders (
region_id1 INTEGER REFERENCES regions,
region_id2 INTEGER REFERENCES regions,
PRIMARY KEY (region_id1, region_id2));

CREATE TABLE companies (
company_id                  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
company_name                TEXT NOT NULL,
headquarters_region     INTEGER REFERENCES regions NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE works_in(
company  INTEGER REFERENCES companies,
region_id  INTEGER REFERENCES regions,
PRIMARY KEY (company_id, region_id));
```

I want to translate to SQL this query:

"Retrieve the companies that works in three different regions that two by two share a border. Write for every company the company's name and the names of the 3 regions that share borders, in alphabetical order."

Well I have tried to work with joins and grouping, but I only achieved to get the names of companies that works in three different regions. I really have no idea about how implement this query in SQL or relational algebra.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Thank you for any advice and help!

Comment: "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Is that your homework?

Comment: Try combining `GROUP BY` with `COUNT DISTINCT` and `HAVING`

Comment: It is hard to suggest something solid without seeing table data but "Retrieve the companies that works in three different regions" That part you can easy get with `SELECT companies.company_name, COUNT(*) FROM works_in INNER JOIN companies ON works_in.company  = company.company_id GROUP BY works_in.company HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT region_id) >= 3` and use that result in a subquery and JOIN that with other tables to get the other information you need.. something like this is possible in SQL.. `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ... ) AS alias INNER JOIN table ON alias.column = table.column ...`

Comment: Besides you can also write the `SELECT ...` subquery in a `INNER JOIN` clause like this. `SELECT * FROM table INNER JOIN ( SELECT ...) AS alias ON table.column = alias.column `.. Good luck with your SQL exercises and SQL studies.

Comment: If we do the homework for you, you won't learn much...

Comment: Funny, that same argument applies (maybe more even) to professionals asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The final solution I could come up with is below**, I try to go though the logical steps that took me to get there.
This is in T-SQL. (SQL Server 2016)

### List how many regions a company works in

```
SELECT company_name, COUNT(works_in.region_id) AS count FROM companies 
    LEFT JOIN works_in ON works_in.company_id = companies.company_id
GROUP BY company_name
```

The result is like this (test data included below):

[image: Results]

### See which borders does a certain region have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT region_id1, region_id2 FROM region_borders 
INNER JOIN works_in w1 ON region_borders.region_id1 = w1.region_id
INNER JOIN works_in w2 ON region_borders.region_id2 = w2.region_id
WHERE (region_id1 = 1 OR region_id2 = 1)
```

[image]

### List which adjacent regions a company is working in:

```
SELECT * from regions where exists (SELECT region_id1, region_id2 FROM region_borders 
INNER JOIN works_in w1 ON region_borders.region_id1 = w1.region_id
INNER JOIN works_in w2 ON region_borders.region_id2 = w2.region_id
WHERE (region_id1 = regions.region_id OR region_id2 = regions.region_id)
AND w1.company_id = 4
AND w2.company_id = 4)
```

This is for company 4, this will be generalized later.

[image]

### Putting it all together:

```
SELECT company_name, COUNT(works_in.region_id) AS count FROM companies 
LEFT JOIN works_in ON works_in.company_id = companies.company_id
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT region_id1, region_id2 FROM region_borders 
    INNER JOIN works_in w1 ON region_borders.region_id1 = w1.region_id
    INNER JOIN works_in w2 ON region_borders.region_id2 = w2.region_id
    WHERE (region_id1 = works_in.region_id OR region_id2 = works_in.region_id)
    AND w1.company_id = companies.company_id
    AND w2.company_id = companies.company_id
)
GROUP BY company_name
HAVING COUNT(works_in.region_id) = 3
```

This lists the companies that work in 3 adjacent regions. **I left out selecting the actual results you need**, you should be able to build on this and finish the exercise.

Comment: Thank you really a lot! I was getting crazy in understanding relations between bordering regions, but not only in SQL, just reasoning on a very normal table drawn with a pen on a sheet.